# Error while installing DB Browser for SQLite for my windows 7(64 bit) pc

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-browser

i am new here... recently i face a problem while installing DB Browser for SQLite  for my windows 7 pc.. after completing installation i can not run it anyway.. i dont know why... please help me.. i use the following link for installation
 https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases/download/v3.9.0/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.9.0-win64.exe

Comment: We are not general software tech support, and since you've provided NO useful details, we cannot help you. This is not a jobs board where you "hire" someone to fix your problems. You post exactly what's happening, you post exactly what you want to happe, you explain how it's NOT happening, then wait.

Comment: sorry sir, but i actually want to confirm that the download link is correct or not.. and if not from where can i find the actual link to download the DB Browser for SQLite? And thank you sir for your reply..

Comment: asking for software/downloads/links is explicitly off-topic.